Can't use mouse and keyboard over KVM switch
I'm using a frame.work laptop with Ubuntu 24.04 installed, connnected via USB/HDMI to a VPFERT VP-SW220 KVM, which is also connected to my windows work laptop; formerly connected to my desktop PC. On the new laptop, here's the output of lsusb:
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 32ac:0002 Framework HDMI Expansion Card
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 32ac:0014 Framework Laptop 16 Numpad Module
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0e8d:e616 MediaTek Inc. Wireless_Device
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 27c6:609c Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Goodix USB2.0 MISC
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 32ac:0012 Framework Laptop 16 Keyboard Module - ANSI
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05e3:0625 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB3.2 Hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:8156 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB 10/100/1G/2.5G LAN
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 32ac:0010 Framework Audio Expansion Card
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

I'm moderately new to linux (one of those consistent backsliders; hit a major issue, go back to using the windows partition most of the time, eventually just expand windows over top of the former *nix partition... decide to try again later, rinse, repeat) so derp-level help would be greatly appreciated; thanks!

Resolved it - it's a Framework issue. The modules on the Framework 16 don't provide enough power for the KVM unless you're in ports 1 or 4.

Please delete the question as it has nothing to do with Ubuntu.
